# Can I have multiple clients login to the same VPN User?

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2019, l2tp

I am using L2TP with IPSec on Windows Server 2019, and was wondering if its necessary to have a separate user for each tunnel.

At the moment there is only one windows user that can login to the VPN. If there were 3 people that wanted to connect, would they all need a different user? Or can they all login with the same user?

Probably a noob question, but I have to explain to my boss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can all login with the same user.  However, that is bad practice.  Each user should have their own connection and login credentials.  It makes troubleshooting and auditing easier.  For example, say one of the three users logs in from a public WiFi location and erases data from your server.  You wouldnt know who it was.  Alternatively, if one user was having trouble and you wanted to disable the login while troubleshooting.  Then all users would be unable to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may, just know all of the devices/clients need to be connected in some way. An app., Computer pairing, a newer product ect.